# Online websites that provides the i'rab?

Tags: quran

Are there websites that along with translation also give the i'rab of the Quran?

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic, there's https://tafsir.app/. Alongside looking for tafsir of the Ayah it looks up for it in books like Tafsir Ibn Ashur and other Nahw-related tafsir books in the "لغة وبلاغة" sections. Tafsir Ibn Ashur provides i'rab of each verse words, but I'm not sure whether it was translated before.